# iOS 8 AutoLayout changing the position of a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, autolayout

I'm working on an app that I had originally made for iOS 7 which worked perfectly fine, but now after moving to iOS 8, things aren't working properly anymore. Basically, I have a view with a button. When I tap that button, another UIView with a UITextField "slides" up onto the screen from a position below the visible screen area. The problem comes when I tap the UITextField to type into it, where a keyboard comes up, but the view with the UITextField goes back to its initial position off the screen. This was not happening in iOS 7, so I'm assuming this has something to do with the changes to autolayout for iOS 8. Does anyone know what I can possibly do to fix this? I would rather not turn off autolayout if I don't have to, as a good portion of my app depends on it.

Here is some code to show you what I'm referring to. In my example, "locationField" is the button that gets tapped, and "locationView" is the UIView that slides onto the screen:

```
- (IBAction) locationFieldTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self slideViewUp:_locationView];
}

- (void) slideViewUp:(UIView *)slidingView {
    if (viewIsSlidUp) {
        return;
    }

    CGRect frame = slidingView.frame;
    int availableHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;

    // don't move view up if it's already moved up or in the process of moving up
    if (frame.origin.y < availableHeight) {
        return;
    }

    viewIsSlidUp = YES;

    // move view just off screen for animation start, in case it's not already there

    frame.origin.y = availableHeight;
    slidingView.frame = frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        CGRect newFrame = frame;
        newFrame.origin.y = availableHeight - CGRectGetHeight(frame);
        slidingView.frame = newFrame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: When using auto layout, you should not set any frames. You should move your views by modifying their constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the constraints of the view you're animating in iOS 8 and the autolayout system then deals with the rest. You can create an IBOutlet to an NSLayoutConstraint and simply change its constant property. Then you call the layoutIfNeeded method on the edited view's super view in the animation block.